# About relation between max value and column name

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I have a question about relation between max value and column name.

My table is shown below:

===========================

basinID StationID Rainfall

LPS      C0R540   101.5

LPS      C0R600   13.5

LYS      01U050    23

LYS      01U080    3

===========================

I need to find max value on basinID and StationID also show.

the answer is as shown below:

===========================

basinID StationID Rainfall

LPS      C0R540   101.5

LYS      01U050    23

===========================

I have tried many methods but finally it is failure.

How should I do  ??

Comment: show your mysql query

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT t1.basinID, t1.StationID, t1.Rainfall
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.basinID = t2.basinID AND t1.Rainfall < t2.Rainfall
WHERE t1.basinID IS NULL;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` works on the basis that when t1.Rainfall is at its maximum value, there is no t2.Rainfall with a greater value and the t2 rows values will be NULL.

Comment: Old school. Nice (if a bit slow)

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SElECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Rainfall DESC) x
GROUP BY `Rainfall`
```

This works because in mysql you're allowed to not aggregate non-group-by columns, in which case mysql just returns the first row.

Comment: Yes, it's basically an an undocumented hack (unless you include the comments section of the relevant page of the documentation)